# Error CS1501: No overload for method `NewDeck' takes `0' arguments (CS1501)

Tags: c#

I am attempting to create a function that will create a set of cards
that can be randomly input into a list, but despite researching the solution
I can not figure out what I need to place in the parentheses when I called my 
function, and when I return its variable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BlackJackGameX
{
    public class Deck
    {
        Random rNumber = new Random();

        List<Card> Cards;
        List<Card> ShuffledDeck;

        public int iValue1 = 11;
        public int iValue2 = 2;
        public int iValue3 = 3;
        public int iValue4 = 4;
        public int iValue5 = 5;
        public int iValue6 = 6;
        public int iValue7 = 7;
        public int iValue8 = 8;
        public int iValue9 = 9;
        public int iValue10 = 10;
        public int iValue11 = 10;
        public int iValue12 = 10;
        public int iValue13 = 10;
```

I can not figure out what I need to put in the NewDeck parentheses.

```
        public Deck()
        {
            Cards = NewDeck();
        }

        public void Shuffle()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 51; ++i) 
            {
                int c = rNumber.Next (1, 53);

                ShuffledDeck.Add(Cards[c]);
            }
        }

        private List<Card> NewDeck(Suit CardSuit, FaceValue CardValue, int iValue)
        {
            var AllSuits = new Suit[]
            {
                Suit.Spades,
                Suit.Hearts,
                Suit.Clubs,
                Suit.Diamonds
            };

            var AllFaces = new FaceValue[]
            {
                FaceValue.Ace,
                FaceValue.Two,
                FaceValue.Three,
                FaceValue.Four,
                FaceValue.Five,
                FaceValue.Six,
                FaceValue.Seven,
                FaceValue.Eight,
                FaceValue.Nine,
                FaceValue.Ten,
                FaceValue.Jack,
                FaceValue.Queen,
                FaceValue.King
            };

            var AllValues = new int[]
            {
                iValue1,
                iValue2,
                iValue3,
                iValue4,
                iValue5,
                iValue6,
                iValue7,
                iValue8,
                iValue9,
                iValue10,
                iValue11,
                iValue12,
                iValue13
            };

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 12; j++) 
                {
                    Card newCard = new Card(AllSuits[i], AllFaces[j], AllValues[j]);
                }
            }
```

I can not figure out what I need to put in the NewDeck parentheses

```
            return NewDeck ();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ShuffledDeck[1].CardValue);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't seem to be using the cardsuit, cardvalue and ivalue parameters, consider removing them from the newDeck function decleration.

Comment: Thats great cheers :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the signature of the method in question is:

```
private List<Card> NewDeck(Suit CardSuit, FaceValue CardValue, int iValue)
```

you will need to pass in values like the following:

```
return NewDeck(Suit.Spades, FaceValue.Ace, iValue1);
```

As Oren has said, inside the NewDeck method you do not use these values. Having the signature like this should also be OK:

```
private List<Card> NewDeck()
```